# Any extension for Calculating nutrition after placing order in magento2.2 enterprise edition admin panel order details

Tags: php, magento2.2

I just want to know that, Is there any kind of extension for **magento2.2** for calculating the nutrition of product(chocolate) from the order details area in admin panel, and need to print these calculated nutrition as PDF.

**Note :** we can add the ingredients as attribute for the individual products.
If the customer chose 3 products and the 3 products may have different ingredients and from these ingredients we have to calculate the final nutrition from the order details area.

From this scenario is there any extension available please let me know.

Comment: No need further actions, Already done.